# Trigger to detect changes in firebase

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, psql

When a child is updated or created in firebase database, I need to trigger a REST API. How to go about it?
Tried using "stream" function, but in order to invoke stream everysec will have to create a cron job. I would like some trigger to be done through firebase to call API.

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is a mess. What it has to do with Django ? What did you tried so far ? Could you please, share some code.

Comment: My intention is to sync firebase data with psql, i'm using django api to do one time data dump currently. But i need to update my psql database when data is updated in firebase. To do so i need trigger to invoke my api when firebase data is updated

Comment: You say you "Tried using 'stream' function", which I assume means [streaming data from the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming). That API should not require a CRON job to constantly poll, but it will require a process that keeps its connection open. If you want us to help with that implementation, update your question to show what you tried.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i used "pyrebase" package to stream changes. Anyway i went ahead with cloud functions to resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Firebase Realtime database you can use Cloud Functions that trigger on a write to your database. Here is [some docs that explain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions) it a bit more. An example from the docs is below. Basically on a create to the database at `/messages/{pushId}/original` it will trigger this code that you could process your logic in or call your rest api. You can also do this with [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) as well.

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```

Comment: I think onWrite would be better since the requirement is for both create and update

Comment: Correct `onWrite` would better suit this instance if its the same endpoint, but if they are different rest APIs for create and update. you'd want `onUpdate` and `onCreate`.

Comment: Will try this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("node/you/want/to/observe");
ref.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) { //here you do your API call });
```

BTW - you don't have to 'invoke stream every sec'. You create **on** listener that will trigger whenever condition is met. Juts remember to [turn it **off**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off) when you're done.

Comment: Please be aware that above answer assumes you run this code in the browser. Solution by Jack Woodward is 'server side' and probably more suiting your needs (especially if your API call will require credentials)

Comment: sure,willl try. Thanks